# Calling json postData properly

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Hello stackoverflow members. So I wanna call this action nested array in json to Action Component but I dont know how. If I could get some help that would be highly appriciated

```
import React from 'react'
import data from "../data.json";
function Action() {
    return (
        <div>
         {data.map((postData) => {
        console.log(postData);
        return(
            <div key={postData.id}>
              <h1 >{postData.action.name}</h1>
            </div>    
        )})}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Action
```

```
[
 {
    "action":[{
    "id":"0",
    "image": "src=fsdf",
    "price" : "60$",
    "name" :"cs" 
    },
{
    "id":"1",
    "image": "src=fsdf",
    "price" : "6$",
    "name" :"whatever" 
}],

   "adventure":[{
        "id":"10",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price" : "60$",
        "name" :"Cs" 
        }]
}
]
```

Comment: you json array not correct . As `"adventure"` is object key value pair. But you are globally wrapped with array

Comment: No That's perfectly fine :) Check in json validator

Comment: @Tequila: Please have a look into the code sand box... I have created a working solution for your code :) Hope this helps

Comment: @Tequila: If you find my answer helpful, Do consider Voting for it and Accepting it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your code to something like this:

```
import data from "../data.json";
//...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {data[0].action.map((postData) => {
          return (
            <div key={postData.id}>
              <h1>{postData.name}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`data` is an array with one object with two properties: `action` and `adventure` that are arrays.

---

As `prasanth` points out given your current data you could also remove the outer most array and make data a single `object`.

Then you can just map over `data.action`.

---

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-paper-j49nj?file=/src/App.js:152-164)

Comment: I have a question is it going to be hard making  a search Component that is filtering all those  arrays and then displaying them

Comment: It's out of the scope of this question, but you can go about that multiple ways. For example let's say you have an `App` component that has an `Action` component that displays the data and a search component that has an input and filters the data. If you keep the data in the state of the component above `Action` and your search component (`App` component for example) you can pass it around to both components. If you want to update something from a child you can pass an update function as props. Useful to read: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html.

Comment: If you don't want to keep passing props around you could think about using something like [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your `data.json` file in the public folder if you want to access the data in `json` format and then make use of `useEffect` Hook and fetching data within `useEffect()` Hook itself to get the data.

**Here is the WORKING DEMO on Codesandbox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/json-fanda-stydg

**FULL CODE:**

```html
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("./data/data.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setData(json);
      });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {data.length > 0 &&
        data.map((postData) => {
          console.log(postData);
          return (
            <div key={data.id}>
              {postData.action.map((action) => {
                return <h1>{action.name}</h1>;
              })}

              <p>
                {postData.adventure.map((adventure) => {
                  return <h1>{adventure.name}</h1>;
                })}
              </p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**JSON:**  You JSON is perfectly fine :)

```
[
  {
    "action": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "cs"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "6$",
        "name": "whatever"
      }
    ],

    "adventure": [
      {
        "id": "10",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "Cs"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Its not completly that, bcs that adventure array is going to another component, anyway thank you.

Comment: :) You are welcome . Hope you got your query solved from Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I tried to map over both action and adventure  and showed few of the results from those :) Had no proper context. Anyways :) This is also a often used technique to loop over sub-arrays to show data. Hope this will help you in future :)

Comment: I have a question is it going to be hard making a search Component that is filtering all those arrays and then displaying them

Comment: No my friend :) You can search stuff depending on how you are setting your component and rendering data within... Ultimately we must first create a state for all our data. And render that state (mapped) over component. You may need filter() and includes() method to search stuff :) How you do things will depend on how you will implement your state

Comment: This repo would help you get the filter logic :) https://github.com/emmeiwhite/roboFriends

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227035/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-tequila).